# CSS: Calling any element with same attribute

Tags: html, css, attributes

Is there a way to call any element on a website with the same attribute?
If I have the following elements for example:

```html
<h1 example="true">Test</h1>
<p example="true">Test 2</p>
```

can I call them together? So without using the following -

```css
h1[example="true"]{
    color: red;
}
p[example="true"]{
    color: red;
}
```

OR

```css
h1[example="true"], p[example="true"]{
    color: red;
}
```

I just need a way to call EVERY element with that attribute being true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do directly by specifying the **CSS [attribute] Selector** without any tag-name preceding it as follows -

```css
[example="true"]{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<h1 example="true">Test</h1>
<p example="true">Test 2</p>
```

So, in the above example, every element having `example` attribute set to `true` will be selected by the CSS selector and the CSS styling will be applied to all of them.

We can use attribute selector like `a[attr=value]` or `h[attr=value]`. Consider the above code to be like - `*[attr=value]` which selects all elements having that attribute.

Comment: So easy and I didn't think about it... Thanks a lot! That helps a lot if you are doing front-end and half back-end to flag elements without function to someone who's doing the rest of the back-end.